# Bootstrap3: When switched to mobile, dock the right column horizontally to the bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

My client wants to have 2 columns on medium and big screens, but when a screen is small, the left column should take up full width, while the right column, containing tabs, should turn into a horizontal row/bar, that contains those tabs and is docked the the bottom of the (mobile) screen.

The reason for this is that the space is limited. The left column is more important, so display that one but still give convenient way to access tabs from the other column.

The docked bottom row of tabs should resemble bottom nav on Android/iOS apps!

Is there a way to dock a row to the bottom of the screen (visible area), apart from making it absolutely positioned?

Comment: are you using jQM? if yes, post some code.

Comment: Not really, I mistakenly added jquery-mobile tag, will remove it now

Comment: You should keep your questions clear and concise. Stick to a single issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
```

doesn't give you the result you want. You should use

```
position: fixed;
```

You can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) more details about this subject.

Comment: You are so right. I haven't used this option before but it seems to do just what I need. Of course, I'll need to sort other issues as well so stay tuned if you want to help.